# How to get the time to the first bit on a WebResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Using C#, I need to determine the time it takes to begin receiving response from a WebRequest (for now, I'm not worried about the time it takes to download the full response).

From what I can understand, to do this I need to use the asynchronous methods of WebRequest. Here's what I've come up with:

```
public TimeSpan TimeToFirstBit(string url)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  request.Accept = "*/*";

  DateTime? firstBit = null;
  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

  IAsyncResult asyncResult = request.BeginGetResponse(
      (async) => { firstBit = DateTime.Now; },
      null);

  asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
  request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

  TimeSpan result = start - firstBit.Value; 
  // Previous line generates a System.InvalidOperationException: 
  // "Nullable object must have a value."

  return result;
```

}

This results in "Nullable object must have a value." This seems to indicate that the WaitOne() and EndGetResponse methods aren't actually waiting for the async call to complete, as I thought they were supposed to.

So how do I wait until BeginGetResponse() is completed? And is this indeed the correct way to determine the response time for a request?

Comment: Can't you use the WebClient class? It has a DownloadProgressChanged event you may handle.

Comment: You usage of async features makes no sense. You are waiting on the async result immediately? It's not async then.

Comment: @Adriano - I will look into that, thank you. 

usr - I'm not interested in performing the operation asynchronously, it simply seems like the necessary means to get the information I need.

Comment: @James, your callback gets invoked at exactly the same time that a call to GetResponse (synchronously) would have returned. No difference. It is all-o-nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know the latency between request and response on the wire, use a network packet sniffer such as Fiddler. I'd have more confidence in timing figures from a packet level tool than from in-process timers. In-process measurements may be slightly skewed by including the .net stack overhead. If what you want to know is how quickly the server responds, you don't want to include the client overhead.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to layer-in packet-level monitoring/timing into my existing code (which does more than just check server response times)? I'll check to see if Fiddler has an API.

Comment: FiddlerCore might be what you're looking for.